# Getting a link to an OWNCLOUD file with the file name

Tags: php, debian, apache2

I have downloaded the debian12 apache php7.4 mariaDB config, I have deployed Owncloud, I want to use files uploaded to the cloud for external forms, I need to get links to files containing the file name and extension, is it possible to do this?
I looked everywhere and couldn't find how to do it correctly.
For example.
Now I get links like
mydomain.com/index.php/apps/files/?dir=/TEST&fileid=42#pdfviewer
And me need to get something like
mydomain.com/index.php/apps/files/?dir=/TEST&file=testfile.pdf
and when you clicked on this link, the file was not downloaded, but opened for viewing

I tried to create links using information on forums, but I never found anything useful

Comment: Not sure if that is directly possible using any mechanism provided by Owncloud itself. You could probably create something similar to what https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/master/apps/files/download.php contains yourself though - it appears that directly takes the file name (plus path) via a GET parameter named `file`. In there, they perform a check if there is a logged-in user first - which won't be the case in your scenario, I am assuming, so that should probably be removed. [...]

Comment: [...] Make sure that this can't be used to download any files you _don't_ want anonymous users to be able to download then though! (Like by limiting it to a specific folder, and then checking if the passed `file` value starts with that.) And the `OCP\Response::setContentDispositionHeader` on line #56 would also need to be removed, because that will force a _download_, whereas you want to open the file directly inside the browser.